# Exception calling "Remove" with "0" argument(s): "The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have added a migration using `Add-Migration`, Now If I run `Remove-Migration`, it reverts the migration and remove the generated migration file successfully, but gives the error in Package Manager Console also. I could not figure out the exact reason behind it and side effect of it. Is this EF Core bug?

**Package Manager Output:**

> PM> Remove-Migration Removing migration
>   '20180320052521_testMigration'. Reverting model snapshot. Done.
>   Exception calling "Remove" with "0" argument(s): "The given key was
>   not present in the dictionary." PM>

**EF Core Version:** 2.0.1

Comment: [THIS](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7540) issue looks like yours.

Comment: Is your migration still present in [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory] in your database?

Comment: Could it be a bug of old-ish VS? There was an issue removing migration was failing when IDE tried to remove the file via DTE https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11402

Comment: try updating your `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` nuget package

Comment: This is not a solution but a good practice, as migration is not applied it is always better to undo changes than remove migration for a pure snapshot.

Comment: Can you show the content of the migration you are removing/have removed?

Comment: When EF performing migration actions, you can specify project that will contain migrations and startup project that contain reference to EF. So it is possible that error is related to runtime error. Something like reflection removing of collection of "DbSets" or properties of "DbContext" or some ".HasValue" calls or etc. So we cant clarify answer your question without source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application is always building when a migration is added to the Project as mentioned in the previous answers.

This one is not actually a Solution, its more a workaround which is working for me at most.

Try to remove your Migration mit following Command

```
Remove-Migration NameOfMigration
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding or removing a migration, the application is build. So, most likely you have a collection where you're trying to remove an item with a wrong key and the compiler goes through that piece of code while removing the migration.

Comment: It is possible. For example, in .Net Core when doing update-database, startup is executed.